# cant seem to get state.go to work

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the below code to work:

```
    scope.takeTest = function (assessment) {
        console.log(assessment._id);
        state.go('app.tab.assessments', { id: assessment._id });
        console.log('hi');
    };
```

I've left the logs in so you can understand a little better. The first one does output a id so I know that the id: assessment._id actually works.

However when I click this in the browser it doesn't update the link.

I should also point out that when I'm clicking the button to activate the above code I am already on the same satte I want to change to. I just need to add the id to it.

Maybe that is why?

Comment: If you're already on the right page, why click the button?

Comment: Are you injecting the `$state` service into your controller?  How are you invoking the `takeTest` function in your view?

Comment: maybe you should add stateprovider codes with your controller definition.

Comment: MBielski, I'm on the right page but I need to add an ID to change to a model view. Yea I've added the state service

Answer (score 0):

Try as below.

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
  reload: true,
  inherit: false,
  notify: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are injecting `state` instead of `$state` or you misspelled `$state` in `scope.takeTest()`